# Factor the square of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

While calculating some eigenvalues I stumbled upon this root $3+i \pm \sqrt{6i}$

Try as I might I was unable to simplify $6i$, I looked at the given answer and saw that $\sqrt{6i} = \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{3}i$

I set on this for a bit, searched google, but I can't seem to understand who this was done, can anyone explain?

Comment: Do you know [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) and how to find the [polar form of a complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Complex_numbers)? The principal square root $\sqrt{z}$ of an element $z=re^{i\theta}\in\Bbb C$ is defined by $\sqrt{z}:=\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}$

Comment: Square $\sqrt3+\sqrt3i$, what do you get?

Comment: P.S. Further to the answers, do note that $(6i)^{\displaystyle\frac12}=\pm\sqrt3(1+i),$ and that when dealing with complex numbers, the notation $\sqrt{\;}$ isn't a good idea; for example, is the principal root of $-1$ (A) $e^{i \frac\pi3}$ or (B) $-1 ?$

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the definition of complex
$\sqrt{i}
=\left[ e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}} \right]^{1/2}
=e^{i\pi/4}
=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+i)$.
The rest follows.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach in my opinion is to consider the exponential form of the complex number i. We know that $i=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$, so we get that:
$$\sqrt{6i}=\sqrt{6e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}}=(6e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}})^\frac{1}{2}=6^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$$
But then using Euler's formula you get:
$$\sqrt{6i}=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}(\cos(\pi/4)+i\sin(\pi/4))=\sqrt(3)(1+i)$$
Where the $\sqrt{2}$ was cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

$ \sqrt {6i} = \sqrt {6i+3-3} = \sqrt {(\sqrt3 + \sqrt3 i)^2} = \sqrt3 + \sqrt3 i $